# Glass update to XE22, custom voice command with glassvoice.jar not work

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk, google-voice

My project works fine before the glass update to XE22. I used glassvoice.jar to do voice command in the app. Now I replaced the old glassvoice.jar with the new version from https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets . I fixed some bugs due to the new version, but the voice command still not work.

To test I test the whole project from @pscholl github post which seems to be fine, but it turns out it still not working. More, now the voice trigger that prompt the app from "OK Glass.." card didn't work either. But not all of the list in "OK Glass.." is broken, some of my old app still have the voice trigger.

Is there any one have clue about this? Or have the same problem?

Comment: I've similar problem.. XE22

Answer (score 0):

there were a few small commits that were not finished, a quickfix is in the repository now. Should work on XE22 without modifications.

Comment: thanks for the update. Now the weird thing happens, I didn't do any thing to my project not even use your update library and I just left the glass (with the apk already deployed) for the weekend, when I come back the voice trigger and voice command suddenly can work. But the voice command is totally messed up, e.g. when I say "Ok Glass next" it goes backwards instead. Sometimes I just start the app again, and the respond to the voice command is different from last try. So I think this may not be a code issue, but a glass itself is unstable somehow. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: maybe, the code itself is using a service running on Glass, maybe there is something else that needs to be done (like acknowledging a detected phrase etc.), or maybe not keeping the service connection for a long time... Apparently a reboot helped there.